# What does percentage mean on a community wiki answer?

Tags: support

What does the percentage mean when a community wiki answer is marked "2 revs, 2 users 67%"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the answers to the Meta Stack Exchange question

- [What does the % in the Community Wiki box mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/190204)

it is a *crude* approximation of the percentage of the post that was contributed by the user who has contributed *the most* to it.  (This will be the user whose name appears in the footer to the post. Often it will be the user who created the post, but this is not necessarily the case.)